# C typedef for function, how to use - simple example

Tags: c, function, typedef

i will show what i mean:

header:

```
#ifndef _HASH_H_
#define _HASH_H_
typedef void* pKey;

typedef int (*HashFunc) (pKey key, int size);
#endif
```

new header:

```
#ifndef _DICT_H_
#define _DICT_H_

#include "hash.h"

HashFunc HashWord;

#endif
```

Now here is where i dont know what to write, i want to write the `HashWord` function itself

the c file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "hash.h"
#include "dict.h"

typedef struct _wordElement {
    char* word;
    char* translation
} wordElement, *pwordElement;



HashFunc HashWord{
    ......... here i will want to write the Code
}
```

now it gives me an error, how should i write that last line?

maybe

```
HashFunc HashWord(pKey theKey,int number){...}
```

maybe

```
HashFunc HashWord( theKey, number){...}
```

maybe

```
int HashWord (pKey key, int size){...}
```

what is the right way?

Comment: `int HashWord (pKey key, int size){...}`

Comment: Why do you want to `typedef`? what is your use case?

Comment: @ouah: `HashWord` is not a function, but a *pointer*, right? (No?)

Comment: @Jongware well I didn't see there was also this declaration `HashFunc HashWord;` My function definition matches the type of the function pointer type `HashFunc`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> i want to write the HashWord function itself

But `HashWord` is not a *function*, it is a *function pointer*. Define a function matching the signature of the function pointer, `HashFunc`, and assign `HashWord` the address of the function. For example:

```
int HashFunc_1 (pKey key, int size)
{
    return 0;
} 

int HashFunc_2 (pKey key, int size)
{
    return 0;
}

pKey k = ...;

HashWord = HashFunc_1;
HashWord(k, 4);

HashWord = HashFunc_2;
HashWord(k, 4);
```

Comment: @JohnnyF, as an additional note, even if you'd typedefed a function instead of a pointer, you couldn't use the typedef for a definition (only for a declaration); a syntactical restriction of C (it would be hard to define how to name the parameters and would be of little use).

Answer (score 3):

What you wrote is a type that is a pointer to a function

```
int func (pKey key, int size);
```

What you can do is to declare a

```
int func (pKey key, int size)
{
   // do your stuff
}
```

and then

```
HashFunc HashWord = func;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just read the `typedef` keyword again: `Type` + `Define` - define a type. A function is NOT a type in C, when you make a `typedef` like you did, you define a function pointer type. You can then create a variable of this type and assign to it, that's it.

Comment: What do you mean by "A function is NOT a type"?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that in C, i.e. to define a function that should match a `typedef`ed function type.

You simply have to define the function manually to match the type, i.e.

```
int HashWord(pKey key, int size)
{
  ...
}
```

One way to improve this is for the API to provide a macro that does the function head, that way users of the API can be somewhat sure that they're doing the right thing. Of course, introducing a macro for a function head also obscures it, which is not always very pleasant.

A macro solution might look like this:

```
#define DEF_HASH_FUNC(name, key, size)  int name(pKey key, int size)
```

Then you can use it like so:

```
DEF_HASH_FUNC(HashWord, key, size)
{
  ...
}
```

Of course you could also "fold in" the argument names `key` and `size`, but that makes it even more obscure.

Comment: Am I overlooking something or is it impossible for the user to define a function of the wrong type without getting a compiler message at least at some point for the type-mismatch anyway? (Other than with a cast or an old-style declaration.) I fail to see the advantage of the macro.

Comment: @mafso True, it should be impossible. A macro can sometimes be helpful anyway, and be especially good if there is stuff in the callback interface that the API wishes to keep semi-private. Not saying it would be the right choice for this case, but more that in general it *can* be helpful.